# Is it possible to run multiple instances of OBS on Mac OS X?

Tags: video, streaming, command-line-arguments

I've read that using the `-multi` command will allow you to open multiple instances of OBS ([Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/)) simultaneously. I tried adding the parameter via the command line, but it only opens a single instance. Is there a way to do this on my Mac?

```
> open -a OBS.app --args -multi
```

Answer (score 14):

Success! Turns out you don't even need the `-multi` flag, it works when the new instance `-n` flag is included.

```
open -n -a OBS.app
```

[image: asciicast]